# apache mod_rewrite and number of query parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

Here I have an original url:

> /index.php?controller=controller_name&action=action_name&param1=val1&param2=val2

I need a rule that will transform it to:

> /controller_name/action_name/param1/val1/param2/val2/

The issue is I don't know how many *param* out there, *param* may have any name, for example a real case:

> /member/filter/location/us/gender/male/age/20

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
# match query string in the form
#  controller=controller_name&action=action_name&param1=val1&param2=val2
# and rewrite it to /controller_name/action_name/?param1=val1&param2=val2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^controller=([^&]+)&action=([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /%1/%2?%3

# parse the query string from result of rules above
# and create "directories" from key, value pairs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&?([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/%1/%2?%3
```